# Intersection / Union of two regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions

Is there a way to **directly** form a new regular expression when given two regular expressions and the desired operation (Union or Intersection).

$$
(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*\cup
(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*
$$

$$
(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*\cap
(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*
$$

Without building NFAs and doing the operation through them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in this article: http://fox7.eu/wp-content/uploads/a4-gelade.pdf

It is shown there that:  "when constructing a regular expression defining the intersection of a fixed and an arbitrary number of regular expressions, an exponential and double exponential size increase, respectively, cannot be avoided".

Comment: The link is broken, but I found the paper here: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2071372

Comment: Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20141031084156/http://fox7.eu/wp-content/uploads/a4-gelade.pdf